# How to check that my Regex is safe: Unsafe Regular Expressioneslintsecurity/detect-unsafe-regex

Tags: javascript, regex, eslint

I have a helper that checks if a value is float or not ( German numbers have commas instead of dots ):

```js
export const isFloat = (value: string) => {
    const pattern = /^[+-]?([0-9]+([,][0-9]*)?|[,][0-9]+)$/;
    return pattern.test(value);
};
```

However, Eslint shows me this error:

[image]

Is it safe to ignore this rule?

Or should I fix my pattern? How to check that my regex is safe?

#### EDIT 1 ( The Fourth Bird comment )

[image]

#### EDIT2:

I also, that my colleague's function has the same warning!
[image]

This is my eslint configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020,
        sourceType: "module",
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true,
        },
    },

    env: {
        browser: true,
        node: true,
        es6: true,
    },

    settings: {
        react: {
            version: "detect",
        },
        "import/resolver": {
            node: {
                extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"],
            },
        },
    },

    plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
    extends: [
        "next/core-web-vitals",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "airbnb",
        "prettier",
        "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "plugin:sonarjs/recommended",
        "plugin:security/recommended", // this one
    ],

    rules: {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
            1,
            {
                extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"],
            },
        ],
        "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
        "import/extensions": [
            "error",
            "ignorePackages",
            {
                js: "never",
                jsx: "never",
                ts: "never",
                tsx: "never",
            },
        ],
        "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [
            "error",
            {
                components: ["Link"],
                specialLink: ["hrefLeft", "hrefRight"],
                aspects: ["invalidHref", "preferButton"],
            },
        ],
        "no-nested-ternary": "off",
        "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    },
};
```

Comment: Try changing the asterix to a plus if there can be no comma at the end `^[+-]?(?:[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?|,[0-9]+)$`

Comment: I would just adjust the code to accept the commas as expected for the location, but within the program itself, I would use the standard "period" notation as that is more standard within the code. Especially if calculations are going to be done on the numbers. Then when the numbers need to be reshown to a region that uses the comma operator, just replace the period with a comma and show that to the user.

Comment: I tried but the same warning!

Comment: You are right Chris, however, they focus on the German users, so we will adjust it in the future , if they will scale.

Comment: I don't know what the rules are, maybe due to the alternation with the pipe? Without the pipe `^[+-]?(?=[,0-9])[0-9]*(?:,[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I shared the configuration. Also, the rules is implemented in their file: [detext-unsafe-regex](https://github.com/eslint-community/eslint-plugin-security/blob/main/rules/detect-unsafe-regex.js)

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin You could try using assertions only `^[+-]?(?![\d,]*,,)(?![\d,]*,$)(?!,\d+,),*\d[\d,]*$` https://regex101.com/r/VIGQVX/1

Comment: Fantastic man! Thank you so much. Im not expert in regex , how about this `/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g`

Comment: If I run that, the package returns false, but it also does not match anything https://regex101.com/r/gHZGVK/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254779/discussion-between-menai-ala-eddine-aladdin-and-the-fourth-bird).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nesting the quantifier in a repeating group while matching, you can start the pattern with negative assertions to exclude what is not allowed and then match at least a single digit:

```
^[+-]?(?![\d,]*,,)(?![\d,]*,$)(?!,\d+,),*\d[\d,]*$
```

- `^[+-]?` Optionally match `+` or `-`
- `(?![\d,]*,,)` Negative lookahead, assert not `,,`
- `(?![\d,]*,$)` Not `,` at the end of the string
- `(?!,\d+,)` Not `,` then digits and another `,`
- `,*\d[\d,]*` Match optional `,` followed by at least a single digit and then optional digits or `,`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bPC3su/1)

```
const safe = require('safe-regex');
const regex = /^[+-]?(?![\d,]*,,)(?![\d,]*,$)(?!,\d+,),*\d[\d,]*$/;
console.log(safe(regex));

// Output true
```